# Prove that $(v_1+\textsf{U}) \cap (v_2+\textsf{W}) \neq \varnothing$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My question is:

Given $\textsf{V}$ a vector space over a field $F$, and $v_1,v_2 \in \textsf{V}$. Let $\textsf{U}$ and $\textsf{W}$ be subspaces of $\textsf{V}$. Suppose

$$\textsf{V}=\textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$$

With this, prove that $(v_1+\textsf{U}) \cap (v_2+\textsf{W}) \neq \varnothing$.

It kind of makes sense, but I fall quite easily to breaking it down to specific cases and I don't like it.

How can I sum this in a rather direct manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $v_1 = u_1 + w_1$ and $v_2 = u_2 + w_2$ (with $u_1,u_2 \in U$ and $w_1,w_2 \in W$). So $$ v_1 + U  = w_1 + U \quad \text{and} \quad v_2 + W = u_2 + W.$$ Therefore, $u_2 + w_1$ is in the intersection.

Comment: Ko...Koro sensei I didn’t copy you, I swear! Please believe me, don’t get angry!!!

Comment: How does it conclude?

Comment: Don't worry, Tommy-kun.

Comment: What do you mean, vpam? The sum $u_2 + w_1$ is in the intersection, so the intersection is non-empty.

Comment: I can't quite see why it is in the intersection from the first place. 
It might be the tiredness.

Comment: Ah, okay, no problem. Note that $w_1 \in W$ and $u_2 \in U$, so $w_1 + u_2 \in w_1 + U = v_1 + U$ by definition. In the same fashion $u_2 + w_1 \in u_2 + W = v_2 + W$. So the sum is in both spaces.

Comment: Thanks alot Kez'!

Answer (score 2):

Write $v_1$ as sum of $u_1$ and $w_1$ in $U$ and $W$ respectively. Do the same for $v_2$. Now, you have $w_1+U$ and $u_2 + W$. Do you see how to conclude?

Comment: Sorry, But I don't see how to conclude. I reached this stage by myself and didn't manage to push through

Comment: $u_2 + w_1$ belongs to the intersection, and thus it is non empty

Answer (score 0):

Recall that two cosets $v+\textsf{W}$ and $v'+\textsf{W}$ are equal if and only if $v-v' \in \textsf{W}$.

Now, since $\textsf{V}=\textsf{U}+\textsf{W}$ we can write
$$v_1=u_1+w_1 \quad \textrm{and} \quad v_2=u_2+w_2$$
for some $u_1,u_2\in \textsf{U}$ and $w_1,w_2\in \textsf W$. Notice that 
$v_1-w_1=u_1 \in \textsf U$ and then $v_1+\textsf{U}=w_1+\textsf{U}$. Similarly $v_2+\textsf{W}=u_2+\textsf{W}$.

So, the vector $u_2+w_1$ is in both $u_2+\textsf{W}$ and $w_1+\textsf{U}$. Hence 
$$u_2+w_1 \in (v_1+\textsf{U}) \cap (v_2+\textsf{U})$$